# Integration a function of a single variable over a 2-dim measure

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathfrak B(X))$ and $(Y,\mathfrak B(Y))$ be two measurable spaces and let $\mu$ be a finite measure on the product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathfrak B(X)\otimes \mathfrak B(Y)$. Let $f:X\to\Bbb R$ be a bounded $\mathfrak B(X)$-measurable function and define $\nu(A) = \mu(A\times Y)$ to be a measure on $\mathfrak B(X)$. How to show that
$$
  \int_{X\times Y}f(x)\mu(\mathrm dx\times \mathrm dy) = \int_Xf(x)\nu(\mathrm dx).
$$
I guess, this is completely trivial, however I couldn't come with a completely formal solution. Perhaps, that shall follow from some change of variables equality and the fact that $\nu$ is a pushforward measure of $\mu$ under the projection $\pi_X$? Or from the fact that $f:X\times Y\to\Bbb R$ is $\mathfrak B(X)\otimes \{\emptyset,Y\}$-measurable function and both measures coincide on this $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: Can't be it done via a standard argument, i.e. 1) Show that it holds for indicator functions $1_A$ for $A\in\mathfrak{B}(X)$. 2) Show that if it holds for two measurable, bounded functions $f,g$ then it also holds for $f+g$. 3) Show that if it holds for a sequence $(f_n)_{n\geq 1}$ if measurable, bounded functions, then it also holds for $f=\lim_n f_n$.

Comment: @StefanHansen: like monotone class, or like simple functions arguments? I guess, it shall work but I hoped, it shall be more direct.

Comment: This is a simple functions argument. The 3 steps above shows that it holds for any bounded measurable function. I'll think about the problem, and see if it can be done in a more direct way.

Comment: @StefanHansen: thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\pi_X:X\times Y\to X$ be the projection, i.e. $\pi_X((x,y))=x$ for $(x,y)\in X\times Y$. Then $\nu$ is the image measure of $\mu$ under $\pi_X$, i.e.
$$
\nu(A)=\mu(A\times Y)=\mu(\pi_X^{-1}(A)),\quad A\in\mathfrak{B}(X).
$$
Integration with respect to $\nu$ can be described via integration with respect to $\mu$ (but this result relies on a standard argument as described in the comments, see e.g. this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236077/how-expected-value-is-related-to-density-function/237022#237022)): If $f$ is bounded and $\mathfrak{B}(X)$-meaurable, then
$$
\int_X f(x)\,\nu(\mathrm dx)=\int_X f\,\mathrm d\nu=\int_{X\times Y}f\circ\pi_X\,\mathrm d\mu=\int_{X\times Y}f(x)\,\mu(\mathrm dx,\mathrm dy).
$$

Comment: Oh, so one shall go from the RHS to the LHS in the equality in OP. That's nice! Do you have any book source for the pass from $\nu$ to $\mu$ via the projection?

Comment: My immediate thought is that you can't go from the LHS to the RHS, because you can't describe $\mu$ uniquely by $\nu$ (i.e. $\pi_X$ has no inverse function). I'm not sure if you can do something clever to be able to go from the LHS to the RHS though. You can take a look at _Measures, Integrals and Martingales_ by R. L. Schilling. He treats the idea of integration with respect to image measures. Not sure if he treats the explicit case where the mapping is the projection though.

Comment: I see, but that doesn't seem to be necessary - I liked the way you presented the solution. I'm interested though in some book sources on the passing from one integral to another in a general form given for a function $\varphi$ in your linked post - are you aware of any? Most of these results are not hard to proof, but sometimes it's better just to have a proper reference.

Comment: Yes, chapter 14 in the before-mentioned book (maybe I was unclear, but it treats exactly the kind of passing from one integral to another as described in $(*)$ in the linked answer).

Comment: Somehow I've seen before only the 2nd edition of your previous comment, not the last one - sorry. The case when we have a projection I guess is a special case, so of course it's not necessary to have an explicit reference to that particular instance

Comment: No worries :) I accidently clicked add comment, and was in a rush to edit it before the 5 minute mark.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7170/discussion-between-ilya-and-stefan-hansen)

Comment: @Ilya A change of variable result that one can use here is given as   Theorem 3.6.1 in Bogachev.

Answer (score 2):

For a rigorous proof, the question has to be slightly modified since $f$ is not defined on $X\times Y$. So let $\tilde{f}:X\times Y\to\mathbb{R}$. we want to show that $$\int_{X\times Y}\tilde{f}(x)\mu(\mathrm dx\times \mathrm dy) = \int_Xf(x)\nu(\mathrm dx).$$ Now, two functions with the same distribution have the same integral. This is obviously satisfied here, since $\mu\big(\tilde{f}^{-1}(B)\big)=\mu \big(f^{-1}(B)\times Y\big)=\nu\big(f^{-1}(B)\big)$.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I made the identification that $\int_{X\times Y} f\,\mathrm d\mu$ should mean $\int_{X\times Y}f\circ \pi_X\,\mathrm d\mu$