# Change of measure?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $(X,\mathcal A, \mu)$ is a measure space and $g:X \to \mathbb R$ a measurable function. Then $\mu\circ g^{-1}$ is a measure on $\mathbb R$. Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a measurable function.

I would like some help with the following

**Question:** Can I write 
 $$\int_\mathbb{R} f d(\mu\circ g^{-1})=\int_{X} f\circ g \ d\mu \text{?}$$

If so, do I need any other conditions on $g$ besides measurability? This identity falls under which theorem? Is this an example of change of variables or stands alone as a separate fact?

Comment: $f\circ g$ is not defined for $f,g:X\to\Bbb R$

Comment: Thanks Ilya, now it should make sense.

Comment: Well, it certainly holds e.g. for all positive $f$ and all positive measurable $g$ (to assure that $\mu\circ g^{-1}$ is a positive measure). You can show this by approximating $f$ with simple functions. Are these droids you are looking for?

Comment: You don't need extra assumptions on $g$, but you need $f$ to be such that both integrals make sense.

Comment: @Ilya: $g$ doesn't need to be positive in order for $\mu\circ g^{-1}$ to be a measure.

Comment: @StefanHansen: that's why I wrote *a positive measure*. I first wanted to know, whether OP is interested in the signed measure as well. Then condition $f\geq 0$ is meaningless and we need to change it to the one you've mentioned.

Comment: @Ilya: But $\mu\circ g^{-1}$ will be a positive measure, since $\mu$ is, right?

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought, so it has nothing to do with a change of variables theorem. The proof of the equality is easy, if you guys want to write it as an answer (say for $f=\chi_A$) then I will accept it.

Comment: @StefanHansen: oh, that's what you mean - you're certainly right! $g$ is measurable, $f$ is positive - enough. Since you win, would you please put an answer - upvote is on me :)

Comment: @Ilya: Haha, I'd be happy to :)

Comment: @Cantor This *is* the change of variables theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need $g$ to be measurable, since this will ensure that $\mu\circ g^{-1}$ is a well-defined measure. In order to conclude the equality you need $f$ to be a measurable function such that both integrals exist. A dicussion of when they exist is given e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/237022/25632).

Comment: I was looking for the linked answer of yours, btw, to refer the OP, and didn't find it. Not that I remember it was yours