# Calculating $E[X \vert f(X) \leq c]$

Tags: measure-theory, expectation, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ be distributed uniformly on $[0,2]$ and $f(X) = \beta X$, $0 < \beta <1$. Also, let $f(0) = 0$ and $f(X) < X$ for $X>0$. Note that $c,\beta$ are constants. Then:
$$
E[X \vert f(X) \leq c] = \frac{c}{2\beta}
$$

My question is how to derive this using the definitions [here](http://math.arizona.edu/~tgk/464_07/cond_exp.pdf) (and elsewhere). Specifically,
$$E[X\vert Y = y] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x f_{X\vert Y}(x\vert y) dx
$$
with 
$$
f_{X\vert Y}(x\vert y) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}
$$
where I believe $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$, $f_Y(y)$ is the marginal distribution of $Y$.

My attempt at calculating the expectation was as follows:
$$
E[X \vert f(X) \leq c] = E[X \vert \beta X \leq c] = E[X \vert X \leq \frac{c}{\beta}]
$$
Then, some steps I am unsure about,
$$
E[X \vert X \leq \frac{c}{\beta}] = \int_{0}^{c/\beta}x f_X dx = \int_{0}^{c/\beta}x \frac{1}{2} dx = \frac{c^2}{4b^2}
$$
which is not correct... I do get the correct answer from $\int_{0}^{c/\beta} f_X dx$ though, but isn't $E[X] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x f_X dx$? (see equation $(2)$ [at this stackexchange answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/570609/344247)

So I guess I am asking two question:

1) How do to evaluate the conditional expecation using the formulas provided at the beginning. **(This is my main question)**

2) What is the mistake in my approach?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You'd better assume $\beta > 0$ as well.

Comment: Note that $f$ is a map from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$, i.e. $f(x)=\beta x$. For example, the expression "$f(X)<X$" is not well-defined.

Comment: @Math1000 I am a bit confused when you say "the expression "$f(X) < X)" is not well-defined"$. I think you are saying that since $X$ is a random variable, and $f(X)$ is a real number, an inequality comparing them does not make sense? Is that correct? (Now direction at Robert). Thanks for pointing that out. yes, I assume $\beta >0$ as well. I will make an edit

Comment: $f(X) < X$ is a perfectly good event.  I don't know why @Math1000 would say it is not well-defined.

Comment: @user106860 $X$ and $f(X)$ are measurable functions - $f(X)$ is *not* a real number. What does it mean to say that a function is less than another? The usual notion, that $f(X)<X$ when $f(X)(\omega)<X(\omega)$, is simply not true.

Comment: It is a perfectly cromulant notation.

Comment: $\{f(X)<X\}:= \{\omega: f(X)(\omega)<X(\omega)\}$ is indeed well-defined. The statement "Let $f(X)<X$ for $X>0$" is what I take exception to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're conditioning on an event $f(X) < c$, which is rather different than conditioning on $Y=c$ for a (continuous) random variable $Y$.

In general, if $A$ is an event with $\mathbb P(A) > 0$ and $I_A$ is its indicator random variable, ($1$ when $A$ is true, $0$ when it's false), and $X$ a random variable such that $\mathbb E[X I_A]$ exists,
$$\mathbb E[X | A] = \dfrac{\mathbb E[X I_A]}{\mathbb P(A)}$$

In the case where $A = (\beta X \le c) = (X \le c/\beta)$ (where $\beta > 0$) and $X$ has density $f_X$, this translates to
$$E[X |\beta X \le c] = \dfrac{\int_{-\infty}^{c/\beta} x f_X(x)\; dx}{\int_{-\infty}^{c/\beta} f_X(x)\; dx}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be the map $x\mapsto \beta x$ where $0<\beta<1$. Set $Y=f(X)$. It is clear that $Y$ has uniform distribution on $[0,2\beta]$. If $0<c<2\beta$, then we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[X\mid Y\leqslant c] &= \frac{\mathbb E[X\mathsf1_{Y\leqslant c}]}{\mathbb P(Y\leqslant c)}\tag 1\\ &= \frac{\int_0^{c/\beta}\frac12x\ \mathsf dx}{\int_0^{c/\beta}\frac12 \ \mathsf dx}\\
&= \frac{(c/\beta)^2}{\frac12(c/\beta)}\\
&=\frac c{2\beta},
\end{align}
where the equality $(1)$ holds due to $\{Y\leqslant c\}$ being an event.

Answer (score 0):

The conditional density of $X$ given the event $X\leq \frac c\beta$

$$f_{X\mid X\leq c/\beta}(x) = \dfrac{f_X(x)~\mathbf 1_{x\leq c/\beta}}{\int_{-\infty}^{c/\beta}f(s)\operatorname d s}$$

So basically you forgot the denominator.

$$\mathsf E(X\mid X\leq \frac c\beta) = \dfrac{\int_{-\infty}^{c/\beta} x f_X(x)\operatorname d x}{F_X(\frac c\beta)} $$