# How are the change of variables formula from calculus and the change of variables formula for expectation related?

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, change-of-variable

How is the change of variables formula from multivariable calculus
$$\int_{\Omega} f \circ \phi \cdot |\text{Jac}(\phi)| = \int_{\phi(\Omega)} f$$
related to the change of variables formula for expectations?
$$E(g(X)) = \int g(x)f(x)\ dx.$$
Can you use the first to derive the second? Is the link between them made clear using measure theory? If $X$ is a continuous random variable on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$, I know that its expectation is given by $$E(X) = \int_{\Omega} X\ dP.$$
But I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Yes, the link is clarified using measure theory. See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152338/is-there-a-change-of-variables-formula-for-a-measure-theoretic-integral-that-doe.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/243529/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3285425/321264