# Expected value for a continuous random variable

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, expected-value

Let's fix the generic probability space $(\Omega,\Sigma,P)$, and consider the generic random variable $X\colon \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$.

The expected value of $X$ (supposed to exist) is then defined as $E(X):=\int_{\Omega} X\,\text{d}P \in [-\infty,+\infty]$, namely using the Lebesgue integral of $X$ with respect to the probability measure $P\colon \Sigma \to [0,1]$.

When $X$ is a continuous variable, namely when there exists $f_X\colon \mathbb{R} \to [0,+\infty)$ such that $\forall \,x \in \mathbb{R} \quad F_X(x):=P(X \le x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f_X(t)\,\text{d}t$, we have also that $E(X)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} xf_X(x)\,\text{d}x$.

**My question is: how can I show that the general definition of $E(X)$ reduces to the last one for continuous random variables? Can you suggest me a textbook or a source where I can find some help?**

P.S.

I have found here [Wikipedia, pushforward measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure) that $\int_{\Omega} X\,\text{d}P=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \text{d}\mu_X$, where $\mu_X\colon \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \to [0,1] \mid \mu_X(A)=P(X \in A)$ is the pushforward measure of $X$, with $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ the Borel $\sigma$-algebra over $\mathbb{R}$.

I know also that $F_X'=f_X$ and that $F_X(x)=\mu_X((-\infty,x])$, so maybe $\text{d}\mu_X=\text{d}F_X=f_X\,\text{d}x$, but I seriously think this is totally wrong.

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/570348/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3285425/321264

Comment: Wondering why would anyone accept a non-answer.

Comment: I'm studyng probability theory at a pretty elementary level, so I'm trying to avoid measure theory every time I can. I thought that the definition of expected value in its general form must use Lebesgue integral. However, I discovered that it is also possible to give a decent definition only using cumulative distribution function. That helped me a lot. Again, no one else answered my question.

Comment: No one else answered your question perhaps because it was already briefly answered in the links above.

Comment: Yes, but I can't accept a comment, only an answer. The above comment was very useful to me, and in fact I upvoted it. However, even the only given answer has been useful, even if in a different way. However, I agree with you that it doesn't addresses my original question. Am I wrong? However, if my acceptance violates the rules of the site I will remove it.

Comment: A little precisation: with the expression "I can't accept a comment, only an answer", I mean that this site doesn't allow me to accept a comment. I don't mean that I cannot be satisfied by a comment. Just to make it clear. However, thank you very much for the link above!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can I show that the general definition of $E(X)$ reduces to the last one for continuous random variables? Can you suggest me a textbook or a source where I can find some help?

This is the general definition of Expectation taken from [Mood Graybill Boes](http://www.mat.ufrgs.br/%7Egiacomo/Livros/Mood,%20graybill,%20boes%20-%20Introduction%20to%20the%20theory%20of%20statistics.pdf)

[image]

Comment: Wait, I can see that here we are not using Lebesgue integral with respect to a generic measure...Ok I'm pretty confused now...

Comment: I don't see that this answer addresses the question. The question was how to prove that $$ \int_\Omega X\, \mathrm{d}P = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} xf_X(x)\,\mathrm{d}x. $$