# Expected Value in measure theory

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space, and let $X$ be a continuous random variable, i.e., there exists a probability density function $f_X(x)$ such that for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$:

$$\mathbb{P}_X\{(-\infty,x]\}\equiv\mathbb{P}\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)\leq x\}\equiv F_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^xf_X(z)\  \mathrm{d}z$$

Assume $X$ is bounded and non-negative. Prove by definition:

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\int_{\mathbb{R}}xf_X(x)\ \mathrm{d}x$$

---

First I must mention that I'm very new to measure theory and lebesgue integrals, so I apologize if this question is easy and I'm missing something. Anyway, I was able to show by definition that:

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\int_{\mathbb{R}}x\ \mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}_X(x)$$

As a physicist, I would very much like to just do this:

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\int_{\mathbb{R}}x\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}_X(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}\mathrm{d}x=\int_{\mathbb{R}}xf_X(x)\ \mathrm{d}x$$

But of course this is not rigorous at all. So I have no idea what to do here. The only lebesgue integral we were taught to compute was the lebesgue integral of an idicator of some set $S$ (and in that case, of course, the integral would just be the (probability) measure of $S$), so I thought - maybe I should express $x$ as a sum of simple functions (indicators)? But I couldn't eventually work this through. Another crucial thing is the fact that I was given that $X$ is bounded and non-negative, but I haven't used that yet.

Thanks!

Comment: You need [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Formal_definition).

Comment: @Snoop I found that Radon-Nikodym theorem too, but I'm not allowed to use it. We haven't been taught that

Comment: You could do it via $\mathbb{E}X=\int_0^\infty\mathbb{P}(X\geq x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ instead, which is a special case of [Fubini-Tonelli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Fubini%E2%80%93Tonelli_theorem).

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't been taught this either...

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/236077/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/570348/321264.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot use [Radon-Nikodym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem) you can always first define a density function $f_X(x)$ and then obtain a measure $\mathbb{P}$ with which compute Lebesgue integrals. Consider $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),\lambda)$ and let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be positive and continuous (thus, Borel measureable). The function
$$\nu(B)=\int_{B}f_X(x)\lambda(dx), \ \ B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$$
is a measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$. Indeed:

(1). $\nu(\emptyset)=\int\mathbb{I}_\emptyset f_Xd\lambda=0$

(2). Let $(B_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ be pairwise disjoint, then
$$\nu(\cup_nB_n)=\int\mathbb{I}_{\cup_nB_n}(x)f_X(x)\lambda(dx)=\int\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\mathbb{I}_{B_n}(x)f_X(x)\lambda(dx)=$$
$$=\int \sup_{N\in \mathbb{N}}\sum^N_{n=1}\mathbb{I}_{B_n}(x)f_X(x)\lambda(x)\underbrace{=}_{\textrm{Monotone conv. thm.}}\sup_{N\in \mathbb{N}}\sum^N_{n=1}\int\mathbb{I}_{B_n}(x)f_X(x)\lambda(x)=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\nu(B_n)$$
The measure $\nu$ is a probability measure if we also have that
$$\nu(\mathbb{R})=1$$
in which case we call $\mathbb{P}_X:=\nu$. We then have that
$$\mathbb{P}_X(X \in (-\infty,x])=\int_{(-\infty,x]}f_X(x)\lambda(dx)=F_X(x)$$
and we can also comfortably write
$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\int_{\mathbb{R}}x\mathbb{P}_X(dx)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}xf_X(x)\lambda(dx)$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_n:=g_n(X)$, where $g_n(x)=2^{-n}\lfloor 2^n x\rfloor$, s.t. $X_n\to X$ as $n\to\infty$. For any $n$,
\begin{align*}
\mathsf{E}X_n&=\mathsf{E}\sum_{i=1}^{M_n} \frac{i}{2^n}1\{X\in [i2^{-n},(i+1)2^{-n})\} \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{M_n} \frac{i}{2^n}\mathsf{P}(X\in [i2^{-n},(i+1)2^{-n})) \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{M_n} \frac{i}{2^n}\int_{i2^{-n}}^{(i+1)2^{-n}} f_X(x)\,dx \\
&=\int g_n(x)f_X(x)\,dx,
\end{align*}
where $M_n=\lfloor 2^n\|X\|_{\infty}\rfloor$. Using the monotone convergence theorem,
$$
\mathsf{E}X=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathsf{E}X_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int g_n(x) f_X(x)\,dx=\int xf_X(x)\,dx.
$$ .

Comment: This looks good! I know that $||X||_{\infty}<\infty$ since $X$ is bounded. What if $X$ isn't bounded? (but $\mathbb{E}[|X|]<\infty)$

Comment: If $X$ is nonnegative, consider $X_n=X\wedge n$ and send $n\to \infty$. For general $X$ write $X=X^{+}-X^{-}$, as usual. Assuming that $\min\{\mathsf{E}X^{+},\mathsf{E}X^{-}\}<\infty$, the expectation is well-defined (possibly $\pm\infty$).